# Aura component force:recordData picklist onchange event

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller

I have the following markup component:

```
<aura:component extends="c:GenericLightningAuraComponent" 
                implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId"
                controller="MyController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <force:recordData layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.record}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdate}" />
</aura:component>
```

The following aura component uses specific custom object called .

The Revenue__c custom object has several picklist custom fields:

Picklist A
Picklist B
Picklist C
...

I need to handle the onchange event of the first Picklist A and to call function in JS client controller i.e. in the corresponding .js file. The idea is to change the value in Picklist B.

All examples I've found have `<lightning:select`  or `<lightning:inputField` tags.

In my case how can I access Picklist A and to add an `onchange` event to the Picklist A?

I've tried with

```
recordUpdate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
        if (changeType === "ERROR") { alert('alert ERROR'); }
        else if (changeType === "LOADED") { alert('alert LOADED '); }
        else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { alert('alert REMOVED '); }
        else if (changeType === "CHANGED") { alert('alert CHANGED'); }
}
```

I've changed the value in Picklist A but the alert is not visible. All I see is the alert in `if (changeType === "LOADED") { alert('alert LOADED '); }`
 Please explain to make the alert visible in `if (changeType === "CHANGED") { alert('alert CHANGED '); }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [recordUpdated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) available in [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation), which is fired when the record is loaded, updated, or deleted. The event returns two parameter:-

1. **changedFields**   - The fields that are updated on the record when
   the changeType is "CHANGED".
2. **changeType** -    The type of change that fired the event, with values corresponding to "ERROR, "LOADED", "REMOVED", or "CHANGED".

Sample example:-

```
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecord"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="Name,Title,Email"
    targetRecord="{!v._record}"
    targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
    targetError="{!v._error}"
    recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}" />
```

---

```
({
  recordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
 
    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
 
    if (changeType === "ERROR") { /* handle error; do this first! */ }
    else if (changeType === "LOADED") { /* handle record load */ }
    else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { /* handle record removal */ }
    else if (changeType === "CHANGED") { /* handle record change */ }
})
```

Read more here:- [Record Change](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_record_change.htm)

Comment: I've tried what you suggested however it does not work.
`recordUpdate : function(component, event, helper) {`
`var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;`
`if (changeType === "LOADED") { alert('alert LOADED '); }`
`else if (changeType === "CHANGED") { alert('alert CHANGED '); }`

I've changed the value in Picklist A but the alert is not visible.
All I see is the alert in "LOADED" `if (changeType === "LOADED") { alert('alert LOADED '); }` Please explain to make the alert visible in `if (changeType === "CHANGED") { alert('alert CHANGED '); }` as well?